# Old avermedia tv tuner not detected

Tags: tv

I have an internal tv tuner that the system detects as a usb card (avermedia a301). I have been trying to install its drivers but the process crashes everytime as the drivers were built for older kernels.
Is there anyway to get this fixed. I am using Ubutntu 16.04.

Many thanks